# Data column not exist False Error VB

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to make a a form that updates a data table saved along with other data tables in a database using Microsoft Access, but not creating the program in access. When I run the program and click Create, and error pops up that says The column does not exist

[image: Error Message]

Even though when I check the solutions Explorer it shows I am connected and the right column exists

[image]

The code pertaining to this is:

```
Private m_cn As New SqlConnection
Private m_daQuotes As SqlDataAdapter
Private m_daData As SqlDataAdapter
Private m_daUsers As SqlDataAdapter
Private m_cbQuotes As SqlCommandBuilder
Private m_cbData As SqlCommandBuilder
Private m_cbUsers As SqlCommandBuilder
Private m_dtQuotes As New DataTable
Private m_dtData As New DataTable
Private m_dtUsers As New DataTable
Private m_rpQuotes As Integer = 1
Private m_rpData As Integer = 1
Private m_rpUsers As Integer = 1
Private m_drQuotes As DataRow
Private m_drData As DataRow
Private m_drUsers As DataRow
Private neededPassword As String

Private Sub fMainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    m_cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\kophazi\Documents\Databases\Customer Quotes Log Database.accdb"
    m_daQuotes = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Quotes", m_cn)
    m_daData = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Data", m_cn)
    m_daUsers = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Users", m_cn)
    m_cbQuotes = New SqlCommandBuilder(m_daQuotes)
    m_cbData = New SqlCommandBuilder(m_daData)
    m_cbUsers = New SqlCommandBuilder(m_daUsers)
    m_daQuotes.Fill(m_dtQuotes)
    m_daData.Fill(m_dtData)
    m_daUsers.Fill(m_dtUsers)

Private Sub btnpOCreateNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnpOCreateNew.Click
    Dim userNewRow As DataRow = m_dtUsers.NewRow()
    userNewRow("username") = txtpOName.Text
    userNewRow("Password") = txtpOPassword.Text
    m_dtUsers.Rows.Add(userNewRow)
    m_daUsers.Update(m_dtUsers)
End Sub
```

Comment: a) thats a lot of form/class level vars that do not need global scope. b) you could be getting an exception in the form load so it never completes.  Set a breakpoint on the last line of it to see if it is reached. c) never ever store passwords as plain text

Comment: @Plutonix The security on this program is not a huge concern. I'm looking at the connection string, I put breakpoints in all the spots relating to the user table, similar to what you suggested, and found the connection string wasnt connecting right. Maybe if I screw with that a bit

Comment: You are using an OleDB  (Access) connection string with SQL Server providers.  What is the DB actually?

Comment: Put a `Debugger.Break();` line after the `m_daUsers.Fill(m_dtUsers)` line.  Run the program.  When that line is reached, hover your mouse over the m_dtUsers table, select the "DataTable Visualizer" from the magnifier drop down in the pop-up toolbar that appears.  Examine the datatable to see what you got.

Comment: Plutonix appears to have it right.  You are using members of the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace, which is exclusively for SQL Server, for your data access but your screenshot of the Server Explorer and your connection string indicate that you're using an Access database.  You need to use members of `System.Data.OleDb` instead.